# Getting Npm error code 128 while npm install

Tags: node.js, npm-install

npm eror code 128

[image: 1]

I have added public in my bitbucket account, no idea what is the problem here tried installing the latest version of npm, no help

Edit- So this is while I try to run "npm i -f" command for one of my organizations project which is in bitbucket and so I logged in using my personal github account and added my ssh key so the new error is showing as below
[new err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHB4C.png)
I have checked the folder completely(hidden files also), it is empty, also tried deleting that folder also but still same error
PS - node ver - 18.1.0
npm version - 9.4.1

Comment: There are some error regarding your repository permission while fetching branch. Please try with access token during fetching in git.

Comment: Try this: `npm cache clean --force`. Or reinstall npm using the latest version. You don't specify the version

Comment: Refer to [Github's guide to Troubleshooting SSH error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)